# RUN Bat files with AutoIt Number

Tags: batch-file, cmd, autoit

I would like to run AutoIt application, change the number in the edit box AND BASED on this number the BAT file will run.

As example, I would like to change date for today one or any other. Based and when I will run BAT file from AutoIt app, BAT file will use this date.

Is it actually possible???

This is bat file variables:

```
set newDay=22
set newMonth=11
set newYear=2016
```

And this is AutoIt part:

```
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Select
        Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ExitLoop
        Case $msg = $xxx
            Run("n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.bat")
    EndSelect
WEnd
```

Comment: You need to specify how the batch file should receive the numbers -- via command line arguments, at the standard input stream, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass from the autoit code:

```
   While 1
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                ExitLoop
            Case $msg = $xxx
                Run("n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.bat" & " " & $newDay & " " & $newMonth  & " " & $newYear)
        EndSelect
    WEnd
```

And to be received by the batch file:

```
set newDay=%1
set newMonth=%2
set newYear=%3
```

Comment: $newDay = GUICtrlCreateEdit("99", 176, 32, 121, 97) |  Run("n:\xxx\xx\xx.bat" & " " & $newDay). |   set newDay=%1  |  This doesn't work. Do not know why.

Comment: That's because you need to use GUICtrlRead() to get the value in the edit box. Alternatively, using InputBox() may be simpler for you